# Relations between convex objective function and norm between optima.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I try to prove that the $L_2$ distance between current solution and optima decreasing when objective function decreasing. It's like:
$$
f(x^{(t+1)}) \leq f(x^{(t)}) \Rightarrow \|x^{(t+1)}-x^*\|_2 \leq \|x^{(t)} - x^*\|
$$
where $f$ is convex and the gradient of $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continous.
It looks quite clear. However, I can't prove it. Please tell me quick insight of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's untrue.  Consider a function like $f(x_{1},x_{2})=10000000x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Also, can you tell me any assumptions that make the above sentence true?

Comment: Nothing useful.  It's trivially true if $f(x)=\| x - x^{*} \|_{2}$.